# Bash: No such file or directory?

Tags: linux, bash, binary, webserver, wkhtmltopdf

I try to use an executable script (wkhtmltopdf) on a Linux shared webserver (Debian, 64bit). I am pretty sure that I compiled everything correct, but whenever I want to execute the file I get as an response :

```
> ./wkhtmltopdf -H
-bash: ./wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory
```

To be sure that the file is there, here the ls output :

```
> ls
wkhtmltoimage  wkhtmltopdf
```

Furthermore I tested the file command on it, which outputs the following :

```
> file wkhtmltopdf
wkhtmltopdf: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

My question is now :

**Why does bash tells me that there is no 'file or directory', when there obviously is one?**

My first guess would be that the shared server does not allow to execute binary files? But shouldn't it then be a problem of permissions, with a different bash output?

Edit :

```
> id 
uid=2725674(p8907906) gid=600(ftpusers) groups=600(ftpusers)

> ls -l wkhtmltopdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 p8907906 ftpusers 39745960 Jan 20 09:33 wkhtmltopdf

> ls -ld
drwx---r-x 2 p8907906 ftpusers 44 Jan 28 21:02 .
```

Comment: If your filesystem is mounted with "noexec" option you get a "Permission denied.

Comment: What are the permissions?

Comment: Add to your question output of: `id` and `ls -l wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: that looks right, what about perms you see on your curr_dir and parent_dir, ie. `ls -ld . ..` . Good luck.

Comment: Try restarting that instance of bash.

Comment: Thanks for all the input :). I think I really just lack of the interpreter given by @nsilent22

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I bet you miss *dynamic linker*. Just do a

```
readelf --all ./wkhtmltopdf | grep interpreter
```

You should get an output like this:

```
[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

There are high chances that you system lacks the interpreter (`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` in the example). In this case bash would yell `No such file or directory`, just like when the binary itself is missing.

You can try to use a *different* linker. Sometime you can succeed. Just do a:

```
/path/to/the/linker /path/to/your/executable
```

This command:

```
find /lib* -name ld-linux\*
```

will help you find the linkers on your system. Or you can do the `readelf` command on some command that *does* run. It will show you correct, working linker.

**OR**, since you are running Debian system, just do a

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

to install native version of the tool :)

Comment: The output is exactly as you said. How can I now definetly check if  `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`exists?

Comment: Issue a `ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Paste it's output here.

Comment: ls output is: `ls: cannot access /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory` so thx :)

Comment: Yes for one second I stopped thinking :D

Comment: I updated my answer how you can "override" the problem, if the binary isn't linked with exotic libraries.

Comment: Thx for the additional answers. **sudo** I have no admin rights an therefore cannot use apt-get, **different linker** I tried this options but with no success: `find /lib* -name ld-linux\*` outputs: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` and 
`/lib/i686/cmov/ld-linux.so.2` now I tried  `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 wkhtmltopdf -H` with the output `wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: wkhtmltopdf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, the same happend with the other linker. In general I think I cannot use wkhtmltopdf on this shared server ;)

Comment: @Knowledge: Are you sure this machine is 64bit? What `uname -m` outputs?

Comment: `> uname -m` outputs : `x86_64`, so I guess I am running on a 64bit system?

Comment: @Knowledge: Looks like. So, if you don't have admin-rights you can try to manually download the package (e.g. from here: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/wkhtmltopdf/download), and then manually unpack it, and you'll get the binary. But it looks like it depends on lots of other libraries (Qt5 for example), so I think the game is not worth the candle.

Comment: Well done. I had this problem when trying to run a RHEL executable on Ubuntu. You might mention this as a possible reason in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

In my case

```
$ readelf --all ./wkhtmltopdf | grep interpreter # readelf: Displays information about ELF files.
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
```

On a machine where the executable was working:

```
$ ls -lah /lib/ld-linux.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Apr 16  2018 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -> i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
$ dpkg -S /lib/ld-linux.so.2  # -S, --search filename-search-pattern: Search for a filename from installed packages.
libc6:i386: /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

So to fix the problem ([reference](https://www.unixmen.com/enable-32-bit-support-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-greater/))

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libc6:i386  # GNU C Library: Shared libraries (from apt show)
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing the linker was my case as well. I could fix it with the help of nsilent22 answer like this:

```
readelf --all  /usr/local/myprogram | grep interpreter
[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3]
```

But that linker did not exist anymore.

The old situation in `/lib64` was:

```
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
ld-linux-x86-64.so.3 -> ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

So it turned out this was just a symlink to the systems' linker.

Moving over to `/lib64` , which itself is a symlink to `usr/lib64` and creating a symlink over there did not work. I assume that there are to many symbolic link levels after Debian moved everything into `/usr`

However creating a 'direct' symlink

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
```

did the job; `/usr/lib64` now shows:

```
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 -> /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue on my raspberry pi 4 running aarch64 alpine 3.13. Using the answer provided by @vkersten, I was able to determine that I was missing /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1.

I resolved this by installing gcompat with `apk add gcompat`.